# Configure STS with JPA 2.0 using PostgreSQL 9.3

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, postgresql, jpa, spring-tool-suite

I have an old Spring MVC project which I used to run with Eclipse on JBoss and using JPA 2.0 with (I believe) a PostgreSQL 9.1 DB. Also using Maven as dependencies resolver.

I managed to get the project back from an HDD crash but I couldn't get it to run properly using Eclipse/Tomcat so I thought I might use the opportunity to start using STS (Spring Tool Suite) and get a clean project and just re-insert the code where it belongs.

Sadly, I'm stuck at the very beginning... I created a Spring MVC project with Maven support, but can't set up the JPA 2.0 part.

I went to **Project > Properties > Project Facets**, checked JPA and clicked on the freshly appeared link "Further configuration required...".

This brought me to the JPA Facet configuration panel where I can choose from two platforms "Generic 2.1" and "EclipseLink 2.5.x". I could only find some noSQL and Oracle support for EclipseLink so I thought I would go for Generic 2.1 (does that mean it's JPA 2.1 ?).

Now I can choose a JPA implementation "User Library" or "Disable Library Configuration".
I tried importing the .jar defined by this maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

But it just tells me "**The class 'javax.persistence.Convert' is required to be in the selected libraries**".

Maybe Hibernate's version of JPA isn't "Generic 2.1" compliant ?
I've seen a few times "you need to download Hibernate tools" but that didn't change anything.

Also, when I try to create a connection using PostgreSQL, I don't have any driver to choose from and if I want to add one, the only one I'm allowed to add is a jdbc-postgres-8.x driver.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After clicking the "Further configuration required..." link, click the download icon
to the right of the (probably empty) list. That will give you a set of libraries that
you can select and download and then choose from afterwards, such as an EclipseLink library.
See the screenshot

[image: Screenshot of library download dialog]